# how to pass products id with redux count in react native for ecommerce like addtocart function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

making an eCommerce like platform and here I want to `add_to_cart` and show the count on the Icon. and and with count show the product as per the id which stored in array

```
  this is my reducers :-
     const cartItems = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            return [...state, action.payload]
        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
            return state.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id)
    }

    return state
}

export default cartItems
```

in which i am increasing the count as per the item seleted

```
const mapStateToProps = reduxStore => {
 return {
  cartItems: reduxStore
 }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addItemToCart: (product) => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_TO_CART', payload: product })

    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToProps)(ContentPage)
```

only I am getting the count not the cart items and I want to pass `this.state.data.name && this.state.data.img` which getting from the URL!

Comment: Your question is not clear, you may need to include more code or your component state clearly what section you need help with.

Comment: just wanted to pass the api data to the cart pageconst mapStateToProps = reduxStore => {
 return {
  cartItems: reduxStore
 }
}

Comment: hw to pass in props that data?

Comment: once you have done mapStateToProps, you can do `this.props.cartItems`

Answer (score 0):

(Edited) Try updating the state like this:

```
const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],
};

const cartItems = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART':
      return { ...state, cartItems: state.cartItems.push(action.payload) };
    case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id),
      };

      return state;
  }
};
```

And to have access to `cartItems` in the props:

```
const mapStateToProps = reduxStore => {
 return {
  cartItems: reduxStore.cartItems
 }
}
```

Comment: and to get the cartItems?

Comment: What do you mean by get the cartItems? You mean in the component?

Comment: still not getting the items in the casrtlist ?

Answer (score 0):

For passing in additional props if that is what you are asking, `mapStateToProps` also takes an optional props

```
const mapStateToProps = (reduxStore, ...otherProps) => {
 return {
  cartItems: reduxStore
 }
}
```

you can reference the data through `this.props.cartItems`

Comment: still not getting any cartItems ? just getting the count in the Icon ?

Comment: do `console.log` on `this.props` to see the content of props.